# Pimcore capacity: how many visitors, CMS pages-documents, Data Objects can Pimcore Community Edition operate?

Tags: pimcore

Question:
Is Pimcore a right solution for 35 projects with 100k-1million pages each, 1-2 million visitors monthly for each project.

Explanation:
Can you please recommend how to make such decision,
e.g. share your experience building large projects on Pimcore, how scalable is it, which amounts of data can it normally manage?

For example, I have seen projects of the following size working normally on 1 virtual server with database on the same server:

- 500000 data-objects (products) with about 50 characteristics-parameters-attributes.
- 10000 data-objects (products) with 700 attributes is ~15 object-bricks.
  But there were not many visitors, I believe up to 10k monthly.
  Search indexed by Solr or ElasticSearch.
  I usually had only few CMS Documents and never split Pimcore application to multiple servers yet.
  For me, it worked perfect, and I really enjoyed the power of Symfony bundles working with Pimcore.